# NSMutableArray removeAllObjects replaces contents after removal with other items

Tags: iphone, arrays, ios5, nsmutablearray

sorry if the title is worded oddly, not really sure how to say it. I am adding contents of an array of object's from a JSON into another array, so I can do use a sectioned UITableView. However, when I do the `removeAllObjects` function call when I've filled enough for the first section, add them to my array, and start to load up the second, it results in the entire first section being replaces by the second section. Is NSMutableArray at fault, or is it something I am not thinking of?

```
    weekScheduleArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithCapacity:2];
    NSMutableArray *temp = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
    for (int count = 0; count < [jsonObject count]; count++) {
        if (count < 7) {
            [temp addObject:[jsonObject objectAtIndex:count]];
        } else if (count == 7) {
            [weekScheduleArray addObject:temp];
            [temp removeAllObjects];
            [temp addObject:[jsonObject objectAtIndex:count]];
        } else {
            [temp addObject:[jsonObject objectAtIndex:count]];
        }
    }
    [weekScheduleArray addObject:temp];
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Calling `[weekScheduleArray addObject: temp]` **does not** add a copy of `temp` to `weekScheduleArray`; it adds the array itself.  Therefore when you subsequently `removeAllObjects` from `temp` then the array in `weekScheduleArray` is also empty.  You can avoid the issue with:

```
[weekScheduleArray addObject: [temp copy]];
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem is you are continuing to manipulate the exact same mutable array that you just added to the weekScheduleArray. There's a bunch of ways to solve this. You could create a copy when you add it to weekScheduleArray:

```
[weekScheduleArray addObject:[temp copy]];
```

Or you could do this:

```
[weekScheduleArray addObject:temp];
[temp release];
temp = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
[temp addObject:[jsonObject objectAtIndex:count]];
```

And then when you are done your for loop, remember to release temp.

Comment: This would be some what correct if you were working outside of ARC, but to keep down on memory consumption (even though its one alloc), this is not good.

Comment: Um, both options consume the same amount of memory. Whether you use copy or alloc, you are creating a second array. And it would be absolutely correct, not somewhat correct.

Comment: You said *if* outside ARC it would be "some what correct". If outside ARC it would be perfectly correct. Your question did not specify ARC. And you should understand that when you call copy it is doing an alloc for you, so the memory consumption comment is not correct.

Comment: I was going to modify it, however I can't modify past comments unless I just added it. No need to get so defensive. Correct, I did not specify ARC support, and I will remember that the next time.